# Error message "Thread1:signal SIGABRT" on "return 0"

Tags: c, multithreading, return, sigabrt

I wrote a code in C-programming trying to search words in a string and replace this words with other words. 
Everything seems good when it is running, but there is a error happened at the line "return 0" with a message "Thread 1:signal SIGABRT".

I have no clue to track where the problem is. Does anyone have any idea about it?

The following is my code:

```
int main(void){
    char s1[]="ABCDABCD";
    char *s2="BC";
    char *s3="xyz";
    int ReplaceStr(char *, char *, char *);
    char *pps1=s1;
    printf("%s\n", s1);
    ReplaceStr(pps1, s2, s3);
    printf("%s\n", s1);
    return 0;
}


int ReplaceStr(char *pps1, char *ps2, char *ps3){
    if(pps1==NULL || ps2==NULL || ps3==NULL) return 0;
    int n1=strlen(pps1), n2=strlen(ps2), n3=strlen(ps3);
    if(!n1 || !n2) return 0;
    char *sNext=strstr(pps1, ps2);
    char *sNext1=sNext+n2;
    if(sNext==NULL) return 0;
    int count=0;
    char *Tmp=calloc(sizeof(char), strlen(sNext1)+1);;
    if(sNext != NULL){
        strcpy(Tmp, sNext1);
        memcpy(sNext, ps3, n3);
        strcpy(sNext+n3, Tmp);
        sNext+=strlen(ps3);
        count+=ReplaceStr(sNext, ps2, ps3)+1;
    }
    free(Tmp);
    return count;
}
```

- s1: a string for being searched
- s2: the words I want to look for
- s3: the words which will replace s2

Comment: With the values you have, would the result in `s1` be `"AxyzDAxyzD"`? Then you have a problem because there's not enough memory allocated for `s1` to extend it. The size of `s1` is nine bytes, you can't write more without going out of bounds and have *undefined behavior*. Try declaring it with a larger size, like e.g. `char s1[32] = "ABCDABCD";`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It worked. I think the problem is like you said that the new s1 will go out of the allocated memory. So will the string not extend automatically unless I allocate a new memory for it?

Comment: Arrays in C have a size set at the time of the compilation. C doesn't have run-time expandable strings. If you need dynamic strings you have to manage their allocations and reallocations at run-time yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure at the moment why you claim the error is at the line `return 0` at the end of `main`.  What IDE/compiler are you using?

Try rewriting your code like this:

```
int ReplaceStr(char*, char*, char*);    // {1}

int main() {
    char *s1="ABCDABCD";   // {2}
    char *s2="BC";
    char *s3="xyz";
    char *pps1=s1;
    printf("%s\n", s1);
    ReplaceStr(pps1, s2, s3);
    printf("%s\n", s1);
    return 0; 
}

int ReplaceStr(char *pps1, char *ps2, char *ps3){
    if(pps1==NULL || ps2==NULL || ps3==NULL) return 0;
    int n1=strlen(pps1), n2=strlen(ps2), n3=strlen(ps3);
    if(!n1 || !n2) return 0;
    char *sNext=strstr(pps1, ps2);
    char *sNext1=sNext+n2;
    if(sNext==NULL) return 0;
    int count=0;
    char *Tmp= (char*) calloc(sizeof(char), strlen(sNext1)+1);  // {3}
    if(sNext != NULL){
        strcpy(Tmp, sNext1);
        memcpy(sNext, ps3, n3);
        strcpy(sNext+n3, Tmp);
        sNext+=strlen(ps3);
        count+=ReplaceStr(sNext, ps2, ps3)+1;
    }
    free(Tmp);
    return count; }
```

At edit {1}, I declared the function you are to use before `main`.

At edit {2}, I changed `s1[]=""` for consistency.  It irked me.

And at edit {3}, `calloc` returns a `void*`, and so you have to cast it to the type of pointer you want.